# Multiplying the return of a function by another function

Tags: python, function

I'm new to functions and don't understand what happens in this exercise:

```py
def foo():
    print("Hello from within foo")
    return 2
def bar():
    return 10*foo()
print foo()
print bar()
```

Output:

```
Hello from within Foo
2
Hello from within Foo
20
```

In the 'bar' function I'm trying to multiply 10 by the value of the `foo` function (which is 2). The problem is that, when I print the bar function, it prints the text of the foo function and the 20. I just want to get 20 when I print the bar function, what can I do and why this happens?

Comment: Please do NOT post code screenshots or links to them. Post your formatted code as text.

Comment: If you had `2` and `10`, how would you multiply them together? So, if you have `foo()` and `bar()`, how would you multiply them together? It's the same thing. Your terminology is off, which is clouding your thinking. The functions do not "have" values, so "the value of the foo function" doesn't make sense. They *return* values. Similarly, you do not "print the bar function"; you print *the value that it returned*.

Comment: Wait, I think I misunderstood you. You want to call `foo` from within `bar`, which causes a `print` to occur; but you want the `print` not to occur when you do that? I'm afraid you're out of luck. Functions do what you write them to do. You need to think about the overall logic of your program, in an actual context that makes sense (not an abstract toy example), and figure out what code *should actually be part of the function*, and what code should be outside the function, making use of its return value.

Comment: Yes, I dont want the print to occur in the bar function. I just want bar() to return 20 after multiplying 2 (the return value of foo() ) by 10.

Answer (score 2):

the issue is because you already defined the **foo()** function to print text, and so whenever you call it in the **bar** function it will still print the text in the foo function.

If you only want the **bar()** function to return **20** and not print any text, then you would need to remove the **print** line in the **foo()** function. So something like,

```
def foo():
    return 2

def bar():
    return 10 * foo()

print foo()
print bar()
```

Comment: Oh, okay, But I want an output like:

Hello from within foo
20

There is a way to do it?

Comment: @JesúsA.Fajardo it's certainly possible to do that using string formatting, but that's an entirely different question. Consider updating your question, doing some research to see if you can figure out the answer for yourself, or posting another question.

Answer (score 1):

A function is just a piece of code that will be executed when you call it. The return value will "replace" the function call once the return statement is done inside the function but to get to that stage you HAVE TO execute all the code before the return statement.

Once the code in your function gets to the return statement, the function stops executing. You cannot change the return value again. For example

```
def hello():
    y = 1
    y = y + 1
    x = 1
    return x
    x = 2
    return x
```

will always return 1 and it will ALWAYS execute both of the assignments to y even if we never use them.

I think it would help to think of the return value more as an exit code of a program than a function value.

Comment: Nice, I think now I understand better the behavior of the "return" thing. Thank you!